# Actionscript 3 Removing multiple childs

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-statements

Basically, I want to remove my play/pause buttons on a condition when someone goes to a new page, but at the same time, if my video is active, it will remove it as well.

Currently this is my code to remove them.

```
    if (header.text == "Gallery") {
    myvid.stop();
removeChild(myvid);
trace("stuff got removed")
removeChild(iplaybtn); removeChild(istopbtn); removeChild(iplaybtn2); removeChild(istopbtn2);
removeChild(play0); removeChild(stop0); removeChild(play1); removeChild(stop1);

}else{
trace("gallerybutton has been click.");
myvid.stop();
removeChild(myvid);
```

}

---

Problem is, it works, as in, it will remove the video and THEN the buttons, but the issue is, if the video isnt active, it doesn't remove the buttons =/.

Can't figure out how to make a conditional statement which will apply to both, but it will check if both have been complete or just do both.

GAAAH help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "if the video isnt active"
Also, i don't know what the header.text is, but i assume a textfield.

I think you just want a OR statement, like this:

```
if (header.text == "Gallery" || <<code if video is active>>) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer looks correct, you're probably looking for logical operators. These are the operators you can use:

```
|| (OR operator) will run the code if any condition is true.
&& (AND operator) will run the code if all conditions are true.
! (NOT operator) will run the code if the condition is not true (i.e. false!)
```

You can find more information on operators and their usage here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html

I'm not sure if you're removing everything or just some things on stage, but if you're looking to remove everything you can also use:

```
for (var i:int = (numChildren - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
  removeChild(getChildAt(0));
}
```

or alternatively

```
while (numChildren > 0) {
  removeChildAt(0);
}
```